# How can I proceed to solve these two sums : $\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^n \min(i,j)$ and$\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^n \max(i,j)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^n \min(i,j) \ \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ \ \sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^n \max(i,j)$$
I'm just curious about these two sums, I'm conjecturing that :
$\min(i,j)=i$ or $j$ so the sum will be :
$$\sum_{i=0}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
I'm sure that it's wrong, so how can I solve it ?

Any useful thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

The key thing is to realize for WHICH values of $i,j$ do we have $\min(i,j)=i$ vs $\min(i,j)=j$.

So, consider breaking the sum up into cases:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\min(i,j)=\underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=i}^{i}\min(i,j)}_{i=j}+\underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\min(i,j)}_{i<j}+\underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\min(i,j)}_{i>j}.
$$
Can you see how to proceed from here?